# How to convert T object to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have following method

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, Guid> MustExistInDatabase<T, TEntity>
    (
        this IRuleBuilder<T, Guid> ruleBuilder,
        TEntity obj
    ) where TEntity : class
{
    if (obj == null)
        return ruleBuilder.Must(id => false)
            .WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' {PropertyValue} not found.");

    var isCollection = obj.GetType().GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable)) != null;

    if (isCollection)
    {
        var list = (obj as IEnumerable<TEntity>); //I get a null here
        
        if (list.Count() == 0)
        {
            //rest of code
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

I want to check whether `obj` is an `IEnumerable` or not, if it's an `IEnumerable`, then I want to convert `obj` into `IEnumerable<T>`, but I'm getting `null` when doing `(obj as IEnumerable<TEntity>)`. What is the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: For `obj as IEnumerable<TEntity>` to work, `TEntity` would need to implement `IEnumerable<TEntity>` (because `obj` is a `TEntity`). We don't know what type of items `obj` represents.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar can I get some code sample on how to implement?

Comment: No, no you can't. Your question and code don't make clear what you expect to happen here. Why do you think it should be possible to cast `obj` to an `IEnumerable<TEntity>` when `obj` itself is a `TEntity`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar `obj` can be a single class like `Customer` or it could be `List<Customer>`, is it possible to know what the `obj` is and handle it accordingly? For example I can tell whether `obj` is a collection or not. But I have problem where I need to actually convert the `obj` into `List`

Comment: `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<TEntity>` are not the same interface.

Comment: Your code expects that `TEntity` is a type that's declared something like this: `public class TestEntity : IEnumerable, IEnumerable<TestEntity>`. Is there a reason why you can't `IEnumerable<TEntity>` and can't just work with `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft sorry because I'm not really an expert, so basically I want to call this `MustExistInDatabase` and I want to pass something like `Customer` object or `List<Customer>` object. So my method would be detect if it's a single class or list of class and check if the id exist in those object. Is this possible?

Comment: @warheat1990 I expect you'll need a separate method for `IEnumerable<TEntity>` and singular `TEntity`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar: I tried that, but the overloading doesn't work as when I pass a list, it will always go to singular `TEntity` method.

Comment: Perhaps call one method `AllMustExistInDatabase`?

Comment: Theodor answer works for me, no overload needed or any mumbo jumbo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) operator, the combines a type-check and an assignment:

```
if (obj is IList<TEntity> list)
{
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

If the `obj` can be cast to `IList<TEntity>`, the `list` variable is assigned to the converted result. This feature is available from C# 7.0 and later.

- [Declaration and type patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns).